# Multiple commands produce 'DemoApp/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Elete.app/Frameworks/AWSCore.framework'

Tags: ios, xcode, amazon-web-services, cocoapods, ios17

Multiple commands produce 'DemoApp/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Elete.app/Frameworks/AWSCore.framework'

Xcode version: 15.0.1

macos: Sonoma(14.0)

Macbook Air M1

Testing device is iPhone 11 pro and iPhone 15

iOS Version : 17.0.1

Comment: Please do not post pictures of text. You should replace all of your images with the actual error messages and text files, as text, copied and pasted into your question. Pictures can't be searched or referenced, they are harder to read, and they are harder to post.